# Error Message "Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'"

Tags: python, opencv

Just a standard Screen Grab code here :-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
    Speed = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (1060,510, 100, 60)))
    cv2.imshow('Speed' , Speed)
    

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Returns the aforementioned error for the imshow line, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageGrab` is not getting any images. Take a look at `Speed.shape`, it'll be an empty tuple `()`. There's an issue with your bbox.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
    # your bbox order or params was wrong: left_x, left_y, right_x and right_y
    Speed = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (100, 60, 1060, 510)))
    cv2.imshow('Speed' , Speed)
    

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Hats off to you man, it takes (left_x, left_y, right_x and right_y) as arguments instead of (left_x, left_y, width, height). Thanks a lot!